# Service account : Google Analytics v4 : Error User does not have any Google Analytics account

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I'm trying to add function in firebase to get the analysis data of users.

```
code: 403,
>    errors: [
>      {
>        message: 'User does not have any Google Analytics account.',
>        domain: 'global',
>        reason: 'forbidden'
>      }
>    ]
```

I'm getting this error when I run it to the command prompt. Not sure where I'm doing mistakes. I got the access token but the error was generated  by the `reports.batchGet` code.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

const gClientEmail = functions.config().google.client_email
const gPrivateKey = functions.config().google.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')

const { google } = require('googleapis');

const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(gClientEmail, null, gPrivateKey, 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly', '');

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();

google.options({ auth: oauth2Client });

exports.init = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  jwtClient.authorize((err:any, tokens:any) => {
        if (err) {
            throw (err);
        }

        oauth2Client.setCredentials({
            access_token: tokens.access_token
        });

        var analytics = google.analyticsreporting('v4');

        var req = {
            reportRequests: [
                {
                    viewId: VIEWID, 
                    dateRanges: [
                        {
                            startDate: "10daysAgo",
                            endDate: "today",
                        },
                    ],
                    metrics: [
                        {
                            expression: "ga:users",
                        },
                    ],
                    dimensions: [
                        {
                            name: "ga:date",
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
        };

        analytics.reports.batchGet({
            'auth': jwtClient,
                'resource': req,
            },
            function(err:any, response:any) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    });
});
```

I got one solution in which they have said to add the `gClientEmail` to each site's user in analytics dashboard. I don’t want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only Google Analytics 4 Property in your account, you can't use Google Analytics Reporting API because work only with Universal Analytics Property.

**API v4 is not API for GA4**.

For GA4 API you have to use Analytics Data API: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1